# How can I tell if my Intel Core CPU supports SLAT?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I am planning to create Windows Phone 8 applications, which are developed alongside Hyper-V. However, my current Core 2 Quad doesn't support a required feature called SLAT.

How can I be sure the replacement CPU supports it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific processor

Comment: This may help http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1401.hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel's implementation is called EPT (Extended Page Table) and AMD's is RVI (Rapid Virtualization Indexing).<sup>1</sup>

All first, second, and third generation Intel Core i3/5/7 processors support it. And all Core i7's support it regardless of generation. Most fourth gen Core i3 & 5's  have support, with some exceptions.<sup>2</sup>

For earlier processors, see the second footnote.

<sub>Footnotes:</sub>

<sub>1. From [Second Level Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Second_Level_Address_Translation&oldid=561955464) on Wikipedia.</sub>
<sub>2. Refer to the [Intel® Virtualization Technology List](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology).</sub>